# Visual Studio test explorer window does not find my tests after NUnit extension implementation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, test-explorer

I'm implementing a testing solution in Visual Studio 2013 Professional. I've chosen NUnit (version 2.6.4) as test framework.  I have installed the NUnit test adapter in order to execute my tests also inside Visual Studio. Everything worked properly until I entered a NUnit extension class to get asserts failure messages...
Before this class implementation inside the Visual Studio Test Explorer all my test classes, and related methods, were listed properly; after the extension implementation when I rebuilt my solution then the test list does not appear any more (the test explorer window is visible, but when I build/rebuild my solution nothing is listed).

All my classes are `public`, each test class has been decorated with the `[TestFixture]` attribute, each test method with the `[Test]` one.
Below my extension class:

```
using System;
using COLL = System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Core.Extensibility;
using NUnit.Core;

namespace UTDirectPLM
{
 [NUnitAddinAttribute(Type = ExtensionType.Core)]
 public class ExtensionToLog
 {
   // the wrong behaviour occurs also if I leave empty the class body.
 }
}
```

What am I forgetting?

Comment: In your demo code, you don't have your addin class implementing the `IAddIn` interface, are you doing that in your actual implementation? [NUnit Documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunitAddins&r=2.4)

Comment: Yes i have... but now I note that when I build my solution everything SEEMS ok... but NUnit throws an exception; the build output is this one: `------ Discover test started ------
NUnit 1.2.0.0 discovering tests is started
Exception System.InvalidCastException, Exception thrown discovering tests in C:\...\UnitTestProject.dll
NUnit 1.2.0.0 discovering test is finished
== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.4271482) ==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the NUnit core 2.6.4 version.  I can reproduce it with 2.6.4, but using the 2.6.3 core - even with the 2.6.4 framework makes it work.  So that is a workaround.  All I needed to make it work or not was to change the nunit.core.interfaces.dll to the 2.6.3 version. (As you implement things, you would of course need to change all the used core dlls to the 2.6.3 version)

As NUnit v2 is no longer being maintained, all work is now focused on NUnit 3.  You could look into V3, even if it is still in beta (beta 2 out now). It has a different and [hopefully] better way of extension too. Take a look at the wiki at https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Action-Attributes

Comment: I will try your suggestion. Anyway, in past (2-3 months ago) I coded an extension to log fail messages using NUnit core 2.6.4 version and everything worked fine... I've looked to this old solution and I've noted that in past I used NUnit Test Adapter version 1.2.0.0, while now NuGet Packet Manager provides the 2.0.0.0 version.

Comment: Following yor answer this is the problem... the actual version of NUnit Test Adapter provides the version 2.6.4 of the nunit.core.interfaces.dll . The 1.2.0.0 NUnit Test Adapter version provides the 2.6.3 one. Note that to execute tests inside Visual Studio you need the dll of the test adapter and not the dll placed inside the NUnit program folder... the dll in NUnit program folder must be used to work with the NUnit GUI ([here more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344903/nunit-extension-does-not-work-running-tests-through-the-nunit-gui)) .

Comment: To be clear: as Terje S. has suggested, I've solved my problem by substituting the old version of the NUnit T.A. nunit.core.interfaces.dll with the dll provided by the 1.2.0.0 NUnit T.A. one.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this.  I'll register this as a bug on the 2.6.4 version and follow up from there. (Or if you would like to do it, feel free - at https://github.com/nunit/nunitv2/issues

Comment: is this bug fixed or not? I'm still working using NUnit 2.6.3 but, as I'm moving on Windows 10 I would like to update the NUnit version to 2.6.4

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but the cause was that while the NUnit NuGet package was installed, the NUnit Test Adapter for VS2013 NuGet package was missing. There were no messages to suggest this as the problem.